# How to secure postfix on Ubuntu Server

Tags: security, postfix

I am setting up a new VPS server with LEMP. The only piece missing now is the mail server. Do I need to do something special to make it secure? or it is already secured when the installation is completed?

I think the right term is hardening postfix, does it make sense?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a lot of guides online regarding the config and steps for 'hardening' postfix.

This one courtesy of http://security-24-7.com/hardening-guide-for-postfix-2-x/

**Hardening guide for Postfix 2.x**

Make sure the Postfix is running with non-root account:

```
ps aux | grep postfix | grep -v '^root'
```

Change permissions and ownership on the destinations below:

```
chmod 755 /etc/postfix
chmod 644 /etc/postfix/*.cf
chmod 755 /etc/postfix/postfix-script*
chmod 755 /var/spool/postfix
chown root:root /var/log/mail*
chmod 600 /var/log/mail*
```

Edit using nano or vi, the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and add make the following changes:
Modify the myhostname value to correspond to the external fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the Postfix server, for example:

```
myhostname = myserver.example.com
```

Configure network interface addresses that the Postfix service should listen on, for example:

```
inet_interfaces = 192.168.1.1
```

Configure Trusted Networks, for example:

```
mynetworks = 10.0.0.0/16, 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.1
```

Configure the SMTP server to masquerade outgoing emails as coming from your DNS domain, for example:

```
myorigin = example.com
```

Configure the SMTP domain destination, for example:

```
mydomain = example.com
```

Configure to which SMTP domains to relay messages to, for example:

```
relay_domains = example.com
```

Configure SMTP Greeting Banner:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
```

Limit Denial of Service Attacks:

```
default_process_limit = 100
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 10
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 30
queue_minfree = 20971520
header_size_limit = 51200
message_size_limit = 10485760
smtpd_recipient_limit = 100
```

Restart the Postfix daemon:

```
service postfix restart
```

Comment: very impressive, tks

Comment: I also think that you should include disabling the VRFY command so that usernames cannot be easily enumerated.  postconf -ev disable_vrfy_command=yes

Comment: Note that /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/master process **can** run as root and that's ok - see  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71922