# flood attack from my Ubuntu server

Tags: networking

Our Network administrator called me today and said there is a flood attack coming from my IP Address.Why is my server do that? Is there any fix for that?
Thank you! im new in using ubuntu.

Comment: What is your server running? Which OS? And which version? It sounds like it's been compromised by either malware or a hacker. It's probably become part of a botnet.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to see open network connections

```
netstat -atu -p


(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 xxx:domain              *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:microsoft-ds          *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:50277                 *:*                     LISTEN      21497/skype     
tcp        0      0 *:netbios-ssn           *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        1      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:33429      yyy.yyy.yy.y:ipp        CLOSE_WAIT  19460/opera     
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:35816      yyy.yyy.yy.y:http   TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:35791      yyy.yyy.yy.y:http   TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:35775      yyy.yyy.yy.yt:http   TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:58245      yyy.yyy.yy.y:https  ESTABLISHED 20773/chrome    
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:52227      yyy.yyy.yy.y:5228 ESTABLISHED 20773/chrome    
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:35831      yyy.yyy.yy.y:http   TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:52911      yyy.yyy.yy.y:https  ESTABLISHED 20773/chrome
```

With this you will see which IP is connected and the pid of the process. Then disconnect service with kill process

```
sudo kill -9 21497
```

This will kill skype connection in our example. Kill all connections you don't want on your server

Bring up `ufw` Ubuntu Fire Wall

```
sudo ufw enable
```

After that you can allow host or network to access a service or all resources

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

this rule will allow all to access the server using port 22 aka ssh

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
```

will allow web access

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.255.255
```

will allow all resources. ssh, http, ftp from 192.168.255.255

This is a first step. Based on the type of server, you must allow all traffic for some resource. For mail server you must allow port `25` for mail sending, `80` for web server ...

If your server is a `web server`, [this Q&A has some tips](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492390/making-apache-secure-on-ubuntu-14-04)

And for a mail server: [How to secure postfix on Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418340/how-to-secure-postfix-on-ubuntu-server) ...

Give us more details for a more precise answer

Comment: I fixed the English a little, please feel free to  rollback my modifications if you think I changed the meaning of something in your answer

Comment: `Bring up ufw Ubuntu Fire Wall` leaving it like that may mislead the reader into believing that `ufw` actually stands for `Ubuntu Fire Wall` (which it does not).